# Разворот массива

Tags: javascript

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
  var arrayTemp = array;
  var arrayResult = [];
  var arrayLength = array.length

  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayLength - 1; i++) {
    arrayResult.push(arrayTemp.pop())
  }
  return arrayResult

}

function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  var arrayTemp = array;
  var arrayResult = [];
  var arrayLength = array.length

  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayLength - 1; i++) {
    arrayResult.push(arrayTemp.pop())
  }

  array = arrayResult;
  return array;

}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue)
console.log(arrayValue)
```

Необходимо написать функцию, котораю разворачивает массив (про метод reverse я знаю). Первая (reverseArray) лишь возвращает измененный массив, а вторая (reverseArrayInPlace) должна менять исходный массив на обратный. Почему этот код возвращает просто пустой массив? В чем ошибка?

Comment: Потому что - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp

Comment: Вот этой строчкой `array = arrayResult;` вы изменяете локальную переменную (формальный параметр функции), но никак не исходный массив.

Comment: @Igor а что с .pop не так?  'arrayResult.push(arrayTemp.pop())'  переносит значение из конца исходного массива в конец нового. Я не совсем понимаю, как в конце функции можно присвоить исходному массиву новое значение 'arrayResult'

Comment: @Jaycobe Никак. Поэтому правильное решение - в моем ответе. А  Ваши две функции - одинаковые.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  var arrayTemp = array;
  var arrayResult = [];
  var arrayLength = array.length

  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayLength - 1; i++) {
    arrayResult.push(arrayTemp.pop())
  }

  array = arrayResult;
  return array;

}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue)
console.log(arrayValue)
```

На самом деле ваш код работает и работает правильно. Чтобы в этом убедиться, давайте выведем значение, возвращаемое функцией вместо того, чтобы выводить значение исходного массива:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  var arrayTemp = array;
  var arrayResult = [];
  var arrayLength = array.length

  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayLength - 1; i++) {
    arrayResult.push(arrayTemp.pop())
  }

  array = arrayResult;
  return array;

}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3];
let res = reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(res); // [3, 2, 1] => работает!
```

Проблема в том, что внутри функции вы переопределяете переменную `array`. Эта переменная изначально указывает на исходный массив `arrayValue`, который вы и пытаетесь изменить "на месте". Вы можете в этом убедиться, добавив в начало функции `console.log(array === arrayValue);`, которое выведет `true`.

Так происходит потому, что массивы передаются "по-ссылке", а не при помощи копирования. Поэтому вы можете свободно изменять значения **элементов** переменной `array`, тем самым изменяя значения этих же элементов переменной `arrayValue` снаружи этой функции.

Однако вот этой строчкой:

```
array = arrayResult;
```

Вы попросту переопределяете значение переменной `array`. Поэтому эта переменная больше не указывает на тот же массив, который был изначально (`arrayValue`). В этом и проблема.

А пустой массив выводится потому, что вы "вырезали" все элементы из исходного массива вот этой конструкцией:

```
arrayTemp.pop()
```

При этом `arrayTemp` === `array` === `arrayValue`.

---

### Что делать?

Прежде всего, не переопределять значение переменной `array`. Во-вторых, не вырезать элементы из исходного массива. В третьих, поскольку для изменения на месте переопределять переменную, ссылающуюся на исходный массив нельзя, то необходимо:

1. Создать **копию** исходного массива (просто присвоить его новой переменной, как видите, нельзя)
2. Работать с копией (только если вы хотите оставить алгоритм с `pop` и `push`, а вообще это совершенно необязательно)
3. Поочередно переопределить элементы исходного массива элементами из обработанной копии.
4. Ничего не возвращать из функции (хотя это опционально и ничего не сломает; просто так принято).

Рабочий алгоритм описал в своем ответе @Igor, можете посмотреть там.

Comment: Функция работает неправильно. Мало того, что развернутый массив это совершенно новый объект, так она еще и исходный массив очищает.

Comment: @Igor автор задал вопрос "в чем ошибка?" Я ответил на его вопрос. И про то, что он массив очищает, я тоже указал (см. последнюю правку). Я имел в виду, что алгоритм с `pop` и `push` в принципе рабочий. Но то, что он не годится в этой конкретной ситуации (для изменения значения на месте) - это да.

Comment: @Igor вы дали автору рабочий алгоритм, а я описал ему, почему не работает тот, что реализовал он. Не вижу причин минусовать.

Comment: @smellyshovel ок, то есть вся проблема состоит в том, что содержимое массива в конечном итоге не меняется. На основе этого я дополнил функцию ещё одним циклом, который заполняет исходный массив значениями из `arrayResult` :
`for(let i = 0; i <= arrayLength - 1; i++) {  
        array.push(arrayResult.shift())
    }`
. Конечно, это не самое рациональное решение(его, на мой взгляд предоставил @Igor), но по крайней мере мне удалось понять в чём проблема и придумать решение. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @Jaycobe выберите, чей ответ вам больше подошёл и отметьте его решением (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: @Jaycobe *то есть вся проблема состоит в том, что содержимое массива в конечном итоге не меняется* - ну оно как бы меняется. Вы ведь его опустошили при помощи `pop`'ов :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = temp;
  }
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы немного неправы. Алгоритм автора вопроса рабочий. Он просто неправильно переопределяет значение. Попробуйте запустите пример, который привел он, но вместо того, чтобы выводить значение arrayValue, выведите значение того, что возвращает функция. Вы увидите, что алгоритм отрабатывает правильно.

Comment: @smellyshovel Если функция называется `...InPlace`, то и разворачивать массив она должна "in-place".

Comment: Так в том-то и дело. Смотрите, там `array` внутри функции указывает на `arrayValue` за ее пределами ровно до тех пор, пока он переменную `array` не переопределяет.

Comment: И поэтому он не изменяет значение `arrayValue`, а возвращает новое, которое теряется (потому что он его не выводит и не сохраняет в переменную никакую).

Comment: А вы в своей реализации `array` внтури функции не переопределяете, а работаете с его элементами, тем самым изменяя значение `arrayValue` за пределами функции.

Comment: @smellyshovel Эта функция вообще не должна ничего возвращать.

Comment: Мы с Вами говорим о разных вещах. Я сейчас попробую в своем ответе описать, что я имею в виду.